# Turing Machine Language Class Recognition

Tags: turing-machines

Would a Turing Machine that cannot move left, but can move right or stay put recognize only regular languages? And how does it compare to a machine the can do the same, but also move left?

Comment: What do you think? You may want to read [_does stay put TM recognizes same languages as standard TM?_](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/37297) and [_single-tape Turing Machines with write-protected input recognize only Regular Languages_](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/22082) to find some ideas and answers.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/42723/755